# In Flutter check a checkbox -> disabled checkbox and text field should be enabled in checkbox check

Tags: flutter, checkbox

I am new to Flutter.

If I click a check box action should be performed.

Eg: Click a checkbox, enable the other checkbox and enable a text field
disable or enable widget only for button click is available.
I don't know how to do it in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use ternary operator ( ? : ) this works same as if does. Most basic explanation about code below when the checkbox is triggered checkBox1 changes and widget rebuilds with checkBox1 equals true now so instead of empty Container currently we are building new CheckBox.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool checkBox1 = false;
  bool checkBox2 = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text("title text"),
            value: checkBox1,
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                checkBox1 = newValue;
              });
            },
          ),
          checkBox1
              ? CheckboxListTile(
                  title: Text("title text2"),
                  value: checkBox2,
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    setState(() {
                      checkBox2 = newValue;
                    });
                  },
                )
              : Container(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok. it was helpful. checkbox click  - text field how to do?

Comment: Can you explain in better words what do you mean? I don't understand the question you asked

Comment: if i click a checkbox, a checkbox and text field should be enabled

Comment: This method will work for single/multi nested widget if u want to show more complex one use it the same method sth == sth ? MyCustomWidgetTree : Container()

Answer (score 0):

```
  final TextEditingController _controllerTE =
      TextEditingController();
  bool cbFlag = false;

TextField(
  readOnly: !cbFlag,
  controller: _controllerTE,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    labelText: 'TE disabled till CB checked',
    prefixIcon: Checkbox(
      value: cbFlag,
      onChanged: (bool? value) {
        setState(() {
          cbFlag = value!;
        });
      },
    ),
  ),
),
```